# GCP Data Loss Prevention API How to deindentify free text column in table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I have a scenario where, a table contains comments column which is free text. The comments column store user feedback and comments. I want to mask/deidentify it using Google Cloud Data Loss prevention API.
While trying to deIdentify, I am observing that DLP API is deindetifying whole content of comment column and not sensitive content only.
Example - if column contains 'My eamil id is xyz@abc.com' then I am get out as '** **** ** **...'

Here while sampling DLP api identifies email address as sensitive data in comments column.

I went through following example -
Free text - https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data
and
Table - https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/examples-deid-tables
However I am looking for example where free text is part of column of specific table and while submitting DLP request I want to submit as whole table only and not separate free text only. Is there any kind of special handling required to achieve this ?

Comment: I didn't catch your issue and what is your blocker. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

- You can do this operation using the method: [projects.content.deidentify](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/deidentify).
- **For example:** The following is the sample table that contains 2 columns and one among them is  a free text column.

| S_No | Free_text_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My email is aaaa@email.com |
| 2 | No Feedback |
| 3 | john@emai.co |

To de- identify email ID information from the Free_text_column, follow the below steps.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/deidentify?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2F%3Cproject-ID%3E%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22deidentifyConfig%22%3A%7B%22recordTransformations%22%3A%7B%22fieldTransformations%22%3A%5B%7B%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Free_text_column%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22S_No.%22%7D%5D%2C%22infoTypeTransformations%22%3A%7B%22transformations%22%3A%5B%7B%22primitiveTransformation%22%3A%7B%22replaceConfig%22%3A%7B%22newValue%22%3A%7B%22stringValue%22%3A%22%23%23%23%23%23%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22item%22%3A%7B%22table%22%3A%7B%22headers%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Free_text_column%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22S_No.%22%7D%5D%2C%22rows%22%3A%5B%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%7B%22stringValue%22%3A%22My%20email%20is%20aaaa%40email.com%22%7D%2C%7B%22integerValue%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%7B%22stringValue%22%3A%22No%20feedback%22%7D%2C%7B%22integerValue%22%3A2%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%7B%22stringValue%22%3A%22%20john%40emai.co%22%7D%2C%7B%22integerValue%22%3A3%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22inspectConfig%22%3A%7B%22infoTypes%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22EMAIL_ADDRESS%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D) is the sample REST API call with all the below resources configured. Replace the “*project-ID*” value in the “*parent*” field with your project ID and execute the call. In the output we can see the email IDs in the Free_text_column are replaced with string "#####".

1. Start with creating the “***DeidentifyConfig***” resource as follows,

- Configure “*recordTransformations.fieldTransformations*” field, this field takes the column name as input and lets us apply transformations to that column within a table.
- Next, configure the “*infoTypeTransformations.transformations.primitiveTransformation*” field, this field takes a rule for transforming a value. We want to replace email ID with string “#####”, so we make use of “*replaceConfig*” field and assign it a value that replaces the email ID in the column data. Refer [DeidentifyConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.deidentifyTemplates#deidentifyconfig) for more information.

2. Next, create the “***item***” resource. Since our input is a table, configure the “*item.table*” field with headers(column names) and rows(values corresponding to each column). Refer [ContentItem](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ContentItem#table) for more information.
3. Lastly, create the “***inspectConfig***” resource that has a configuration description of the scanning process. The “*inspectConfig.infoTypes*” field’s input is the [infotype](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference) that we want to de-identify, in our case it is “*EMAIL_ADDRESS*”. Refer [InspectConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectConfig) for more information.